# Why author said "debugger is a neutral frame of reference" in Software Exorcism?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read the book *Software Exorcism* which is authored by Bill Blunden, I read there is definition about debugger, author said it's a neutral frame of reference. English is not my native language, is there any one can help me understand it, thanks a lot.

Comment: did you google?

Answer (score 1):

A "frame of reference" is a way of looking at something. In this context, a "neutral frame of reference" is a way of looking at a programming problem where the programmer can make observations about a program without affecting it (i.e. neutral). I think the term "objective frame of reference" would also be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

WordWeb [defines this noun phrase:](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FRAMEOFREFERENCE)

> Frame of reference (n): 1) *A system that uses coordinates to establish position.* 2) A system of assumptions and standards  that sanctions behavior and gives it meaning.

This clarifies the meaning in a simple way as while debugging, we not only know where the flaw is but also know its position in coding.